# The nested self-composition of $f(x) = \frac{\sqrt3}2x+\frac12\sqrt{1-x^2}$

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

> The function $f(x)$ is defined, for $|x|\leqslant1$ by $$f(x)=\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}x+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1-x^2}.$$ Find an expression for $$f^n(x)=\underbrace{f \circ  f \circ \cdots \circ f(x)}_{\text{n times}},$$where $n\in\mathbb{Z^+}$.

Now what I did was to first find $f^2(x)$ and my intention was to find $f^3(x)$ and another few cases so as to recognise a pattern. However, $f^2(x)$ is actually very complicated and does not simplify too much.

I am looking for hints on how to approach the problem and not complete solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you note that $x$ may be written as $\cos{\phi}$, then

$$f(\cos{\phi}) = \cos{\left(\phi-\frac{\pi}{6}\right)}$$

On the next iteration,

$$f[f(\cos{\phi})] = f\left [  \cos{\left(\phi-\frac{\pi}{6}\right)} \right ] = \cos{\left(\phi-\frac{2 \pi}{6}\right)} $$

I hope you see the pattern...

**EDIT**

This answer is not totally correct - it is merely formally correct, as pointed out by @achille hui.  The problem lies with the evenness of the cosine.  The iteration for $\phi=0$ produces an incorrect result.  In fact, it is incorrect for $0 \le \phi \le \pi/6$.  What to do?

In the $k$th iteration, consider the sign of $\phi-k \pi/6$:

$$f^{(k)}(\cos{\phi}) = \begin{cases}\cos{\left[\phi - (1-(-1)^k)\frac{\pi}{12} \right]} & 0 \le \phi \le k \frac{\pi}{6} \\ \cos{\left(\phi-k \frac{\pi}{6}\right)} & k \frac{\pi}{6} \lt \phi \le \pi \end{cases}$$

Repeat the process for $k > 6$.

Comment: This is originally what I thought, but it is more complicated that that. Instead, $$f(\sin t) = \sin\left(t+(-1)^{[\frac{t}{\pi}]}\frac{\pi}{6}\right)$$ where $[x]$ is $x$ rounded to nearest integer. The $f$ depends on my $t$ and you $\phi$ in a piecewise linear manner....

Comment: @achillehui: honestly, I do not see where you got that from, nor why this result is invalid.  The input to $f$ remains less than or equal to one in absolute value, so it is a valid input for self-composition.

Comment: @achillehui: I think I see where you are coming from.  But I think we are OK if we restrict $t$ or $\phi$ to $[0,\pi]$, no?

Comment: The problem is $f(f(\cos(t))) \neq \cos(t -\frac{\pi}{3})$ for $t \in [0,\frac{\pi}{6}]$. I discover this when I attempt to plot them...

Comment: If you want to keep $\phi \ge 0$ and $x\ge 0$, $f(\cos \phi) = f(\cos |\phi - \pi/6|)$, and the problem is displaced to iterating $\phi \mapsto | \phi - \pi/6|$. Which almost always get stuck in a $2$-cycle, I think.

Comment: @mercio: I was just figuring that out.  I will append a note.

Comment: @merico, after the $6^{th}$ iteration, $f^{\circ n}(x)$ does stuck in a 2-cycle. i.e. $f^{\circ 6}(x) = f^{\circ 8}(x) = f^{\circ 10}(x) = \ldots$ and $f^{\circ 7}(x) = f^{\circ 9}(x) = f^{\circ 11}(x) = \ldots$